# What is a finite axiomatization of the equality-free theory of coreflexive relations?

Tags: relations, model-theory

This is yet another of my questions on first-order logic without equality. A coreflexive relation is a binary relation $R$ on a set $S$ that is a subset of the equality relation $=$ on $S$. The class of coreflexive relations can be axiomatized by the sentence $xRy \rightarrow x=y$. Certainly, they can't be axiomatized in first-order logic without equality. But, is there a finite axiomatization of the equality-free theory of coreflexive relations, and if so, can someone exhibit such a list of axioms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $R$ is a coreflexive, then whenever $xRy$ we must have $x$ and $y$ satisfy all the same properties we can express. In particular, this means $$(\star)\quad \forall x,y,z[xRy\rightarrow (yRx)\wedge (xRz\leftrightarrow yRz)].$$ Think of $(\star)$ as "symmetry + (atomic) substitution." I claim that in fact $(\star)$ does the job.

To see this, suppose $\mathcal{A}=(X;R)\models(\star)$. Let $\sim$ be the union of $R$ and equality. Then by $(\star)$, $\sim$ is a congruence on $\mathcal{A}$, and in $\mathcal{A}/\sim$ the image of the relation $R$ is coreflexive. A general result which I've used in several answers to your questions - see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432945/what-is-an-axiomatization-of-the-equality-free-theory-of-antisymmetric-relations/432952#432952) - then gives the claim.

Comment: Or $\forall x,y,z[(xRz\land yRz)\to xRy]$ and $\forall x,y,z[(zRx\land zRy)\to xRy]$.

Comment: @bof Ah, yes, that also works, but in my opinion it's a bit less clear: it takes a moment of thought to see that those imply symmetry of $R$ too.